# Arduino + esp8266. Как прочитать ответ GET запроса?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Имею вот такой код отправки команд с arduino mega на esp8266. Get запросы проходят все хорошо. Но мне нужно получить ответ от сервера. Как это можно сделать?

Вывод в консоль:

[image: тут была картинка]

Код:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define RX 50
#define TX 51
String AP = "Home_S2";
String PASS = "supremum";

int countTimeCommand; 

unsigned long lastTimeMillis = 0;

boolean found = false; 
SoftwareSerial ESP8266(RX,TX); 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(115200);

  ESP8266.println("AT+RST"); // Перезагрузка esp8266

  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\""+ AP +"\",\""+ PASS +"\"",20,"OK");

  makeGetRequest("alexey.surnin.com.ua","/push.php");

}

void loop() {
  if (ESP8266.available()) {
    Serial.write(ESP8266.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    ESP8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}

void makeGetRequest(String host, String url){
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
    delay(1000);

    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\""+host+"\",80");
    delay(1000);

    String cmd = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:" + host + "\r\nConnection: close";
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=4," + String(cmd.length() + 4));
    delay(1000);

    ESP8266.println(cmd);
    delay(1000);
    ESP8266.println("");


}

void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
  Serial.print("at command => ");
  Serial.print(command);
  Serial.print(" ");
  while(countTimeCommand < (maxTime*1))
  {
    ESP8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
    if(ESP8266.find(readReplay))//ok
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(found == true)
  {
    Serial.println("OYI");
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  if(found == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Fail");
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  found = false;
 }
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать нормальную прошивку для есп и не спарить их по нормальномой шине с прерываниями?

Answer (score 0):

Максимальный битрейт у ESP8266 - 19200. Видимо, причина в этом.

Comment: "Родной"  битрейт у ESP8266, по которому работают AT команды по-умолчанию - 115200.